# Jquery white spaces

Tags: jquery

Alright so Im trying to check if these fields are just blank (white spaces or no informations has been entered) but if I just press space few times inside of them It wont detect them as empty at all, it will just process it normally.

```
$("form.ajax_call").submit(function(e) {
    var name = $.trim($('#project_name').val()),
        price = $.trim($('#value_change').val()),
        description = $.trim($('#project_description').val());

    if (name  === '') { 
        alert("Please enter the project name"); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    if (price  === '') { 
        alert("Please enter the project price"); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (description  === '') { 
        alert("Please enter the project description"); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure your val()s are returning strings? If there is something we're not seeing here it could return undefined.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces this. Code shown should catch any spaces you enter